# How to make the button which has a kinda image( I need a detail )

Tags: android, image, button, icons, drawable

I would like to know how to make the button which contains a kinda icon.
I made up a LinearLayout first and the button belongs in it.
I tried the the icon to be in the Button by using 'android:drawableLeft="@drawable/***"
The icon was placed to too Left for me.
The button is a little bit long and text and icon are small so there are some space empty.
I mean, I want the icon to be more closer to the text than it was. 
Now, icon is placed to the left and text is in center. 
I want them to be together with a little padding.

I tried to use 'android:drawablePadding=7dip' but it didnt work.
I so want somebody to let me know how to do it.

Have a good day.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Custom Buttons are resizes button stretch image size and below link for custom Button Tutorial link

http://www.thesecretpie.com/2010/07/creating-custom-fancy-buttons-in.html

Thanks..!

Answer (score 0):

There are two techniques. I suggest you look into:

1. [Image Buttons](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)
2. [Image Views](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)

With Image view you can create a button by using an onclick listener which can be created from within your activity or from your xml layout file.